Magento 2.4.4-p3 to magento version 2.4.4-p9 Upgradation
I want to upgrade magento version with cloud base project
Can any one guide me for the Upgradation
current version : Adobe Commerce ver. 2.4.4-p3
Upgradation in : Adobe Commerce ver. 2.4.4-p9

To upgrade Adobe Commerce on Cloud to the latest version of the current version, eg., 2.4.4-p3 to 2.4.4-p9, simply run the command:
composer update magento/magento-cloud-metapackage -w

The -w (--with-dependencies) option is used to update with dependencies.
After that, run bin/magento setup:upgrade to upgrade databases and config files if applicable.
Finally, commit your changes and push it to the remote branch.

composer update magento/magento-cloud-metapackage -w
for this command how to specified version?

i mean add to 2.4.4-p9 in then end of above command?

just run that command without indicating the version, because it is already covered by the config "magento/magento-cloud-metapackage": ">=2.4.6 <2.4.7", in the root project's composer.json

i have the question if i want to updated the 2.4.4-p7 then run the same command?

No, that command will let you update to the latest version, which is 2.4.4-p9. However, I don't find any reason to upgrade to 2.4.4-p7 instead of the latest version. If you still need that, let me know, I'll tell you how to do that.

getting error:
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires magento/magento-cloud-metapackage >=2.4.4 <2.4.5, found magento/magento-cloud-metapackage[2.4.4] in the lock file but not in remote repositories, make sure you avoid updating this package to keep the one from the lock file.

Problem 2
- Root composer.json requires magento/product-recommendations ^6.0, found magento/product-recommendations[5.0.1] but it does not match the constraint.
Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.

I'm away from the keyboard now, but I'll be back to help you out!

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

In the magento.app.yml file replace composer install with composer update. After making this change push your changes to GitHub. This will apply the latest Magento patch as specified in your composer.json file Magento Version.


i want to go with command line no direct changes in files

The solution provided is according to Adobe Cloud guidelines. Command line methods will not be applicable in this case.

can you share the guidelines or a references links?

Sure. https://experienceleague.adobe.com/en/docs/commerce-cloud-service/user-guide/develop/upgrade/commerce-version

@GrazittiDev the official Doc does not say that.
